# Lyapunov function for pendulum with time-varying friction

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes, lyapunov-functions

Consider the pendulum system with time-varying friction:
$$\dot{x_1}=x_2$$
$$\dot{x_2}=-\sin{x_1}-g(t)x_2$$
where, $g(t)$ is a $C^1$ function satisfying
$$0<a<\alpha\leq g(t) \leq \beta<\infty$$
$$\dot{g(t)}\leq \gamma<2,\ \ \forall t\in \mathbb{R}^{+}$$
Now, considering the Lyapuniv function candidate:
$$V(t,x)=\frac{(x_2+a\sin{x_1})^2}{2}+(1+ag(t)-a^2)(1-\cos{x_1})$$
It can be shown that $V$ is positive definite and decrescent for $|x_1|<\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Show that
$$\dot{V}\leq -(\alpha-a)x_2^2-a(2-\gamma)(1-\cos{x_1})+O(||x||^3)$$
where, $O(||x||^3)$ is a term bounded by $k||x||^3$ in some neighborhod of the origin.

**My solution**:
$$\dot{V}=-(g(t)-a\cos {x_1})x_2^2-a(2-\dot{g(t)})(1-\cos {x_1})-a(ax_2\sin{x_1}+\cos{x_1}-1)(1-\cos {x_1})$$
Therefore:
$$\dot{V}\leq -(\alpha-a)x_2^2-a(2-\gamma )(1-\cos {x_1})+h(x)$$
$$h(x)=-a(ax_2\sin{x_1}+\cos{x_1}-1)(1-\cos {x_1})$$
Now, how we can show $h(x)=O(||x||^3)$? Moreover, how to prove that $\dot{V}$ is negative definite?

Answer (score 0):

In order to show that $h(x)=O(\| x \|^3)$ use the Taylor expansion around the origin;
$$h(x)=-\frac{a}{2} x_1^3(ax_2-\frac{a}{6}x_2x_1^3-\frac{x_1^2}{2}+h.o.t)$$
Hence, in a bounded neighborhood of the origin one gets:
$$|h(x)|\leq k|x_1|^3\leq k \|x\|^3$$
for some $k\in \mathbb{R}^{+}$.

To show that $\dot{V}$ is negative definite, first we prove that the following function
$$W(x)=(\alpha -a)x_2^2+a(2-\gamma )(1-\cos{x_1})-h(x)$$
is positive definite. Then, considering the fact that
$$\dot{V}(t,0)=0,\ \forall t\geq 0$$
$$\dot{V}(t,x)\leq -W(x)$$
the negative definiteness of $\dot{V}$ can be inferred. The positive definiteness of $W$ follows from the fact that $x=0$ is indeed, a strict local minimizer since:
$$W(0)=0$$
$$\nabla W(0)=0$$
$$\nabla^2 W(x)\ \text{is continuous and}\ \nabla^2 W(0)>0$$
This means that $W(x)$ is postive definite and $\dot{V}$ is negative definite indicating local asymptotic stability of the origin.